# Renombrar equipo con SQL 7 instalado

Tags: sql-server

Tengo 300 terminales que corren Windows XPMode sobre Windows 7 x64. Cada XPMode tienen instalado un sistema que usa SQL-Express el cual no puedo actualizar porque el sistema que interactúa con él, no soporta nuevas versiones.

Las 300 terminales tienen el mismo nombre "SIM" y hasta el momento eso no era un problema ya que la red se comparía haciendo una NAT interna.  Por otros temas de redes necesitamos eliminar esa NAT y que comparta la placa fisica. Hay algún script que permita hacer un cambio de nombre y toque el tema de las instancias de los SQL-Express para que sigan corriendo?

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar configurando un Alias de DNS en los XPMode, de esta manera ellos interpretarán el nombre SIM como tu lo especifiques aunque tengan un nombre diferente. Para realizar esta tarea debes modificar el archivo Hosts que está en la carpeta

```
%WinDir%\System32\Drivers\Etc\
```

1.- Navega hasta el directorio indicado, da clic derecho sobre el archivo **Hosts** y selecciona **Abrir con** y selecciona un editor de texto tipo **Notepad**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.- Al final de este archivo agrega una línea donde incluyas la dirección IP que tiene configurado en XPMode, y el nombre del alias que le quieres asignar, en este caso SIM.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.- Guarda el archivo asegurándote de seleccionar **Todos los archivos** en **Tipo**, caso contrario el editor le agregará una extensión .txt a tu archivo y no se reflejarán los cambios en tu sistema operativo

4.- Finalmente cierra el archivo, cambia de nombre al XPMode, reinícialo y prueba